# Auto-switching Python Virtual Environments in Visual Studio Code per Directory within a Workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am working on a project in VSCode that has multiple directories, each of which requires a different Python virtual environment. My virtual environments are located in the ~/.virtualenvs directory and my workspace is structured like this:

```
~/.virtualenvs/
│
├── venv_A/
│
└── venv_B/

my_workspace/
│
├── project_A/
│   └── script_A.py
│
└── project_B/
    └── script_B.py
```

I want VSCode to automatically switch to the appropriate virtual environment (venv_A for project_A, and venv_B for project_B) located in ~/.virtualenvs when I open a Python file from each directory within the workspace.
Currently, I have to manually select the virtual environment through the command palette each time.

I have tried looking through the VSCode documentation and searched for guides or tutorials on how to achieve this functionality, but I haven't found anything that addresses this specific issue.
I expected there to be some configuration options either through the .vscode/settings.json file or the workspace settings that would allow me to specify which virtual environment should be used for each directory, and how Pylance, pylint, and yapf should adapt accordingly.

I am aware that VSCode has support for workspaces and .env files, but I'm not sure how to configure it to auto-switch virtual environments based on the directory, and to have Pylance, pylint, and yapf adapt accordingly.

I also found the issue [Select pyenv environment based on folder .python-version file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1167) that is not closed.

Comment: I am also open to putting the env in the directory that needs it, if that helps.

Comment: AFAIK, there are currently no related features available. I have opened [a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21391) for you in Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to open `project_A` and `project_B` as workspaces respectively, and then select an interpreter for the workspace, vscode will remember your choice, and will still use the previously selected interpreter when it is opened next time.

Another approach is to use [**Multi-root Workspaces**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)

- Open a new window and use `Add Folder to Worspace...` to add both folders to the current workspace,

  [image]
  [image]
- Then created separate virtual environments for both folders using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>  --> `Python: Create Environment...` and select the interpreter for the respective folder.

  [image]

  *You can also select the `.py` file in the corresponding folder, and then click the python version in the lower right corner to switch*

**These documents may also be useful:**

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but it appears you can define each project's virtual environment in the Workspace configuration file.

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "project1",
            "settings": {
                "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path_to_project1_virtualenv/bin/python"
            }
        },
        {
            "path": "project2",
            "settings": {
                "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path_to_project2_virtualenv/bin/python"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```